# How to import and use python Levenshtein extension on OSX?

Tags: python, python-2.7, osx-yosemite

I've downloaded the python-Levenshtein archive and extracted Levenshtein dir. So, in result I have the following files structure:

```
Levenshtein
  - __init__.py
  - _levenshtein.c
  - _levenshtein.h
  - StringMatcher.py
myscript.py
```

And the following `myscript.py` content:

```
from Levenshtein import *
from warnings import warn

print Levenshtein.distance(string1, string2)
```

But I get the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Levenshtein import *
  File "/path/to/myscript/Levenshtein/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Levenshtein import _levenshtein
ImportError: cannot import name _levenshtein
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 25):

To install the [python-Levenshtein](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/) package:

- `pip install python-levenshtein`

(This requires [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html), but most modern Python installations include it.)

Answer (score 16):

It seems to me like you did not *build* the Levenshtein package. Go to the unextracted directory of the source you downloaded (for example, `python-Levenshtein-0.12.0/`) and build with:

```
python setup.py build
```

If all went well (apart, possibly, from some warnings), install to your `site-packages` with

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Then I find I can use the package. e.g. from within IPython:

```
In [1]: import Levenshtein
In [2]: string1 = 'dsfjksdjs'
In [3]: string2 = 'dsfiksjsd'
In [4]: print Levenshtein.distance(string1, string2)
3
```

(Note that with your (perhaps unwise) wildcard import you should just be using `distance(string1, string2)` without prefixing with the package name).

Answer (score 13):

**Installation and usage of Levenshtein PIP package on Windows, Mac and UNIX**

Install with **sudo or run as admin**

```
pip install python-levenshtein
```

Import in your code with:

```
import Levenshtein as lev
```

than in your code you can use [Levenstein functions](https://rawgit.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/master/docs/Levenshtein.html#Levenshtein-distance) like this

```
lev.distance('Levenshtein', 'Lenvinsten')
```

which will output

> 4

.

Answer (score -1):

You may try to set environment variables:

append the paths of catalogs `python-Levenshtein-master\build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\Levenshtein` and `python-Levenshtein-master\build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Levenshtein` to your system environment variable `PATH`.