# I am stuck with Levenshtein. It keeps saying "No module named 'Levenshtein'. I have installed Levenshtein. What should I do?

Tags: python, django, levenshtein-distance

```
File "/Users/karanpraharaj/Desktop/IIIT Hyderabad - Spring 2019/Project - CV Jawahar/RMS-master/RMS/Each_Paper_Analytics/views.py", line 7, in <module>
    import Levenshtein
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Levenshtein'
```

Comment: where is the code ? show us the code.

Comment: Please go through this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  As far as the error is concerned: make sure to restart your kernel, the package is installed in the correct directory (manually check it) and also the environment set is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have really installed it:

```
pip list
```

or

```
conda list
```

Also, see the comment below for more info about how to install this module:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29494360/10089328